# What is the best way to test Thrift code in Ruby on Rails using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, thrift

I have a Ruby on Rails App that is using Thrift to communicate with the client.
Right now I have my code inside a controller and whenever the client calls `POST` on a specific path it gets redirected to my controller and there I create a Thrift transport object like this:

`transport = Thrift::IOStreamTransport.new request.body, response.stream`

and then use a Processor and plain old ruby object as a Handler.

However, I need to test this controller (using RSpec).

I can't just use the client code since client code expects a server to be running and thats not available in Test environment.

Any ideas on how to test Thrift code in RSpec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So digging more into the Thrift library and how RSpec works I came up with a workaround of using a custom Transport

```
class TestTransport < Thrift::BaseTransport
  def initialize(delegate)
    @delegate = delegate
    @outbuf = Thrift::Bytes.empty_byte_buffer
  end

  def open?; true end
  def read(sz); @inbuf.read sz end
  def write(buf); @outbuf << Thrift::Bytes.force_binary_encoding(buf) end

  def flush
    @delegate.request.accept = "application/vnd.app.v1+x-thrift-json"
    @delegate.post :handle, @outbuf
    data = @delegate.response.body
    data = Thrift::Bytes.force_binary_encoding(data)
    @inbuf = StringIO.new data
    @outbuf = Thrift::Bytes.empty_byte_buffer
  end
end
```

This code was mostly copied from Thrift's HTTPClientTransport and just where is calls NetIO to post I just call the post on Delegate which is just the RSpec object

Answer (score 0):

If the response from the IOStreamTransport isn't important, and rather just that you build a transport and call something on it, consider mocking your transport.

---

```
let(:fake_transport) { double("fake_transport") }
before do
  expect(Thrift::IOStreamTransport).to receive(:new).with(request.body, anything).and_return(fake_transport)
  expect(Processor).to receive(:new).with(fake_transport).and_return(true)
end
```

Some may say this binds you to your implementation - but you've nicely encapsulated responsibilities in tested objects, so you should expect to use them.

The other alternative is using something like webmock to build a fake response. This takes care of integration tests too, should you want to do those.